# Most efficient way to filter for lowest values in queryset

Tags: python, django

Given:

```
some_list = SomeClass.objects.filter(something=something).order_by('-X','-Y')
```

In English: `some_list` is a filtered list of `SomeClass` objects, ordered by two values, first `X`, then `Y`.

If I then want to limit the number of entries in the list to some value `Z`, I can do this:

```
final_list = some_list[:Z]
```

But what if I want to limit the number of entries to some value, but randomize the "cut-off entries" before I do?  I'm having a hard time describing, so an example:

```
SC  X  Y
 A  2  3
 B  1  2
 C  1  1
 D  1  1
 E  1  1
 F  1  0
 G  0  3
```

If `Z=3` then, using my method, `final_list = (A,B,C)`.  What I want is `final_list` to include A and B because they are clearly above the others(A has greater X than any others, and B is tied for second most X but has greater Y), but seeing as the cut-off would be at C which is `X=1,Y=1`, and there are two OTHER objects "tied" with C, the third slot could be C, D, or E.

I could pull `some_list` apart by hand and examine values and start putting them into `final_list` until I hit Z, but I was hoping there was a better way I don't know of.  As in, less lines of code, less processing power, etc.

So for this example, I would expect one of these outputs, at random:

```
final_list = (A, B, C)
final_list = (A, B, D)
final_list = (A, B, E)
```

If Z = 4, I would expect one of these outputs:

```
final_list = (A, B, C, D)
final_list = (A, B, C, E)
final_list = (A, B, D, C)
final_list = (A, B, D, E)
final_list = (A, B, E, C)
final_list = (A, B, E, D)
```

Hopefully that is clear.

Comment: Can you give a example of output? Do you mean the third slot could be C, D or E by random?

Comment: Added the example outputs.

Comment: Consider this - loop through the pairs till the difference between the values is > 1 (these are your max), then loop through from this point till the difference does not equal 0, these are your "extras"

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That sort of solution is what I meant by pulling apart `some_list` and putting entries into `final_list` "by hand" so to speak.  If that is the best solution, I will accept that answer.  I'm just curious if Django has any built in filters I don't know about, or if a python wizard has some super sneaky way of doing it in less than a  set of nested for loops.

Comment: As your logic is arbitrary by definition ("outputs at random"), I'm not sure how linearly you can write code to do that. My attempt was to best break it down into a set of rules that can be applied "en masse" to the list objects (for example, with a `map()` or `filter()`).

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you.  That's why I threw the question up here though - see if someone knows something I don't.  Seems the long way might be THE way though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simplistic like, annotating your query with the average values of X and Y, and then, picking the values that are above the average. For example, something like:

```
some_list = SomeClass.objects.filter(
                something=something
            ).annotate(
                average_x=Avg("X"), average_y=Avg("Y")
            ).order_by(
                '-X','-Y'
            )

def passes_threshold(x, y, avgx, avgy):
    '''Simplistic function to check if a combination of X & Y is better than
    another. Update to better suit your context.
    '''
    return (x + y) > (avgx + avgy)

# You could use filter instead, if you want all values from the list matching,
# but if you want just until the first few that match,
required_list = itertools.takewhile(passes_threshold, some_list)
```